# Resources to get started with Generative Adversarial Networks (GANs)

Tags: neural-networks, references, gan

Assume the learner is proficient with artificial neural networks. What are some good resources (books/videos/papers/GitHub repo/etc.) to get started with generative adversarial networks (GANs) and become proficient with them?

Answer (score 1):

Given how new the subject is, it's still creeping into curriculum.

Check out this course for a broad overview of the field: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~duvenaud/courses/csc2541/

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have uploaded collection of various GAN models on github repo.
It is torch7 based, and very easy to run. The code is simple enough to understand with experimental results. (keep updating)

https://github.com/nashory/gans-collection.torch